# How to enable harmony in Node for Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js

As I understand it, the following script should compile with the `--harmony` flag.

```
// test.js
function* values() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        yield arguments[i];
    }
}
```

e.g.,

```
node --harmony test.js
```

However, all I get is:

```
test.js:1
unction (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { function* values()
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

I'm running Node v0.10.29.

Does harmony not work on Windows?

Comment: You need to use the unstable 0.11.x release.

Comment: You'll need to install 0.11.x to use generators. `--harmony_generators` is not included in the `--v8-options` for 0.10.x or older.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Node v0.11.x. You can find a copy on the [http://blog.nodejs.org/release/](http://blog.nodejs.org/2014/05/02/node-v0-11-13-unstable/). The download links are buried, so you'll have to dig. Here's a [direct link for Node v.11.13 Windows x64](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.13/x64/node-v0.11.13-x64.msi).